# Unable to get Passport working with React & Node, without Passport authentication works fine

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

This is my first try with PassportJS, and I am following their documentation, which is very hard to understand for me.

My goal is to have a user register through Registration Page, a react component and then use the Login page, a react component as well, to login and redirect to a Dashboard, which is again a react component.

All the above works, but without Passport. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as this is my first time working with it, but it seems to not working. And by not working I mean that I don't see any error message and the login page is not redirecting to dashboard.

Although I have managed to almost put things together, somehow either I am missing something or doing something wrong.

This is my React Login Component, which is sending Axios post request to API:

```js
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newLogin = {
      username,
      password,
    };

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/JSON',
      },
    };

    axios.post('/api/v1/login', newLogin, config).then((res) => {
      return res.data === 'user'
        ? (window.location = '/dashboard')
        : (window.location = '/login');
    });

    setUsername('');
    setPassword('');
  };
```

On Node server.js, the above login post request is sent to controller through router.

server.js:

```js
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/api/v1/register', register);
app.use('/api/v1/login', login);
```

Router.js (Login):

```js
const { loginUser } = require('../controllers/loginController');

router.route('/').post(loginUser);
```

loginController.js:

```js
require('../config/passport')(passport);

exports.loginUser = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/register',
    failureFlash: true,
  });
};
```

This is my passport.js file:

```js
const User = require('../models/UserModel');
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      // Match User
      User.findOne({ username: username })
        .then((err, user) => {
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, console.log('no user'));
          }

          //Match Password
          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (isMatch) {
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    })
  );
};

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findOne(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest removing the redirects from the passport login controller and handling the routing from the react app internally (via react router or otherwise) based on whether or not the app received a user in the response. Here's how I've got it set up in my recent project:

```
//router.js
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const { userModel } = require("../models");
const passport = require("passport");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const bodyParser = express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "50mb" });
const jsonParser = express.json({ limit: "50mb" });
const router = express.Router();
const saltRounds = 10;

router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});
router.get("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy();
  next();
});
router.post("/login", bodyParser, jsonParser, **passport.authenticate("local"),** (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.user) return;
  const date = new Date();
  console.log(`User ID:${req.user._id} logged in at ${date}`);
  res.json(req.user);
  next();
});


module.exports = router;
```

Note how I'm just using passport as middleware, then move on to the next function, which checks for the user it should have received from the previous function

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work as I am not sure how to send response back if I remove the redirect from login controller.

Comment: Use the passport just as middleware, then proceed to a callback function to res.send(user), grab that on the front end and conditionally redirect.

Comment: I added a code sample to my answer, I hope it helps. If not, feel free to reach out to me via the email on my profile! :) For the record, I lost hours of time trying to set up passport too. The documentation is something I've seen a lot of people complain about, and I've had issues navigating it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the right parameters.
Below is a sample for passport configuration.

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const User = require("./../model/user/User");

function setUpPassportConfig(app) {
    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({ email });
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' });
            }

            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return done(e);
        }
    };

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser));

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id).then(user => {
            done(null, user);
        }).catch(err => {
            done(err);
        });
    });

    app.use(session({
        secret: 'secret', // Replace with a secure, randomly generated string in production
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days in milliseconds,
            rolling: true, // This resets the cookie's maxAge countdown with each request.
            // sameSite: true
        }
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
}


module.exports = setUpPassportConfig;
```

Make sure you have allowed cors. And also if you are using it in local, please use IP address instead of localhost.

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000', // Replace with the URL of your front-end app
    credentials: true, // This is important for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
}))
```

In your React app, make sure you pass the withCredentials property as true.
This will make sure the session works from the cookies from the client side.
If you are using axios interceptor, just use

```
request.withCredentials =true;
```